# Using reduce fnt instead of map

Tags: javascript, lodash, ramda.js

Any advise on how can I refactor my function using `reduce`, as I should not use `map` here?

Comment: And why wouldn't you just use map to map the array, the real question is why you're not returning that array, instead of pushing to a new array inside the `map` function

Comment: Why the edit to remove the original code?  The question does not stand alone without it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
function serializeParams (object) {
    return Object.keys(object)
        .reduce((query, key) =>
            Array.isArray(object[key])
                ? query.concat(object[key].map(value => `${key}=${encodeURIComponent(value)}`))
                : query.concat(`${key}=${encodeURIComponent(object[key])}`)
        , [])
        .join('&');
}
```

Or without template strings:

```
function serializeParams (object) {
    return Object.keys(object)
        .reduce((query, key) =>
            Array.isArray(object[key])
                ? query.concat(object[key].map(value => key + '=' + encodeURIComponent(value)))
                : query.concat(key + '=' + encodeURIComponent(object[key]))
        , [])
        .join('&');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `map` instead of `reduce` is appropriate here, you only should map to an array of arrays that you can `concat` before `join`ing.

```
function serializeParams(obj) {
  return Array.protoype.concat.apply([], keys(obj).map(key => {
    let value = obj[key];
    return Array.isArray(value)
      ? value.map(v => key +"=" + encodeURIComponent(v))
      : [key + "=" + encodeURIComponent(value)];   
  })).join("&");
}
```

Since you tagged this with Ramda, you can either compose [`map`](http://ramdajs.com/0.19.1/docs/#map) with [`concat`](http://ramdajs.com/0.19.1/docs/#concat) or use [`chain`](http://ramdajs.com/0.19.1/docs/#chain) right away.